# Calling splice inside map function

Tags: javascript, splice, array-splice

I have following code:

```
var a = [{a: 1}, {a: 2}, {a: 3}];
a.map(function (item, index) {
  console.log('call');
  if (index < 1) {
    a.splice(index, 1);
  }
});
```

But call is printed only two times, and I expect to be printed three times. I know that `splice` has messed up array, but is there some workaround for this behaviour?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a shallow copy of the array:

```
a.slice().map(function (item, index) {
```

By the way, you should maybe use `forEach` since you're not returning any value.

Or even better, have you considered using [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead?

```
var a = [{a: 1}, {a: 2}, {a: 3}].filter(function (item, index) {
  console.log('call');
  return index >= 1;
});
```

Comment: For each has the same behaviour in domain of this problem.

Comment: @user232343 Not if you use `slice`. But I'm not sure to get what you want to achieve, that snippet of code is quite obscure in its intent.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to modify the array while you iterate it, then often times, it's just best to use a plain old `for` loop because you can control the iteration and correct for your modifications.

If your modification is only a deletion of the current element, then a backwards `for` loop is simplest because you don't have to do any corrections when removing the current element.  Here's an example:

```
var x = [{a: 1}, {a: 2}, {a: 3}];
for (var i = x.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (x[i].a === 2) {
        // remove current element
        x.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```

If you don't mind creating a new array as the result of the iteration, you can use other methods such as `.filter()`.

Answer (score 4):

the callback in map has a third argument which is the array it self

```
var a = [{a: 1}, {a: 2}, {a: 3}];
a.map(function (item, index, a2) {
  console.log('call');
  if (index < 1) {
    a2.splice(index, 1);
  }
});
```

This if from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

> The range of elements processed by map is set before the first
>   invocation of callback. Elements which are appended to the array after
>   the call to map begins will not be visited by callback. If existing
>   elements of the array are changed, or deleted, their value as passed
>   to callback will be the value at the time map visits them; elements
>   that are deleted are not visited.